# How can I get data from another function in onCreateView?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-recyclerview, fragment

I have sent data from an activity called ItemDetails:

```
private void AddToCart(String name, String price) {
        OrdersFragment fragment = new OrdersFragment();
        fragment.receiveData(name, price);
    }
```

I want to show the data in recycler view in OrdersFragment when I get it (the list is empty, it is going to be filled with the data passed, as I get orders)

So I get the data here:

```
public void receiveData(String name, String price) {
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
}
```

But I can't access it in onCreateView:

```
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                             @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_rv_orders, container, false);
        txt_name = view.findViewById(R.id.order_item_name);
        txt_price = view.findViewById(R.id.order_item_price);

        txt_name.setText(name);
        txt_price.setText(price);

        return view;
    }
```

I tried various ways of sending data from activity to fragment and this is the only way it actually sent data to the fragment, I just don't know how to access it.
Any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: Android recommends that you use a  "shared ViewModel ", its main purpose is to maintain data during configuration changes and passing data between activities and fragments.

Comment: The problem is that - from the code you shared here - the newly created instance will not be added to the UI. You need to call `receiveData()` on an instance where you know that it is currently being displayed. Some years ago, one would have queried the Fragmentmanager for the current instance of OrdersFragment. But today we would do it as @Shawn suggests: have the Activity pass the data to a ViewModel instance which is also available to OrdersFragment. See also [Share data using a ViewModel](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/communicate)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set your string values in the `receiveData` method of the fragment.
Declare two global variables in the fragment (I assume these are `TextView`)

```
private TextView txt_name;
private TextView txt_price;
```

And initialize them in the `onCreateView` method:

```
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                             @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_rv_orders, container, false);

    txt_name = view.findViewById(R.id.order_item_name);
    txt_price = view.findViewById(R.id.order_item_price);

    return view;
}
```

Finally, set the text values with

```
public void receiveData(String name, String price) {
    txt_name.setText(name);
    txt_price.setText(price);
}
```

I read that you are referring to a `RecyclerView` in your question, if you need to populate a list of that type you will need to create an Adapter in the Fragment and populate it in the `receiveData` method.

Comment: I tried that to, TextView is null so I can't set the value. I thought I could do it without adapter, but thanks, I will try with the adapter.

Comment: If you need to populate a `RecyclerView` you have to use a class implementing `RecyclerView.Adapter` and initialize its views in the `onBindViewHolder` method.